# SQL - Join two queries together efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL queries that query different tables and return similar fields:

```
User - Role - Category - Points
```

and

```
User - Role - Category - Target
```

My queries look like this:

```
select
    acs.UserID,
    acs.RoleID,
    acs.CategoryID,
    sum(acs.Points)
from acs
```

and

```
select
    tb.UserID,
    tb.RoleID,
    tb.CategoryID,
    sum(
        (
            (DATEDIFF(dd, (case when @start >= tb.StartDate then @start else tb.StartDate end), (case when @end <= tb.EndDate then @end else tb.EndDate end)) + 1) 
        ) * tb.dailyMed
    ) as Target
from tb
```

What I would like to end up with is something like this:

```
User - Role - Category - Points - Target
```

Each of the individual queries take less than 1 second to run but when I try to combine them using an inner join it takes over 3 mins to run.

I was hoping there is a more efficient way of doing this but I cannot seem to find one.

*EDIT
My Inner join looks like this

```
select
    acs.UserID,
    acs.RoleID,
    acs.CategoryID,
    sum(acs.Points),
    t.Target
from
    dbo.ActualCacheSale acs
        inner join
            (select
                tb.UserID,
                tb.RoleID,
                tb.CategoryID,
                sum(
                    (
                        (DATEDIFF(dd, (case when @start >= tb.StartDate then @start else tb.StartDate end), (case when @end <= tb.EndDate then @end else tb.EndDate end)) + 1)
                    ) * tb.dailyMed
                ) as Target
            from
                dbo.TargetBucket tb
            ) t on
                t.UserID = acs.UserID and
                t.RoleID = acs.RoleID and
                t.CategoryID = acs.CategoryID
```

Comment: show us your inner join query

Comment: could you show your INNER JOIN statement?

Comment: are you sure you do not need a GROUP BY clause when using the SUM function?

Comment: They are there, i just have not included them in my sample code, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
select
aa.UserId,
aa.Roleid,
aa.CategoryId
Sum(aa.Points) as Points,
Sum(aa.Target) as Target
from
(
select
    acs.UserID,
    acs.RoleID,
    acs.CategoryID,
    sum(acs.Points) as Points
    null as target
from acs

union all

select
    tb.UserID,
    tb.RoleID,
    tb.CategoryID,
    0 as points
    sum(
        (
        (DATEDIFF(dd, (case when @start >= tb.StartDate then @start else tb.StartDatee end),     
    (case when @end <= tb.EndDate then @end else tb.EndDate end)) + 1) 
    ) * tb.dailyMed
    ) as Target
from tb) as aa
group by
aa.UserId,
aa.Roleid,
aa.CategoryId
```

Comment: The union + group by is a little technique that has worked well for me over the years. In specific situations, of course.  I suggested it because you said each individual query was fast.

Comment: I have now joined the union query on to multiple tables and it is still a 3 second query. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure how you're getting a sum without grouping into an aggregate. Anyways, here's my take - hopefully I didn't miss anything:

```
SELECT  P.UserID ,
        P.RoleID ,
        P.CategoryID ,
        P.Points ,
        T.Target
FROM    ( SELECT    acs.UserID ,
                    acs.RoleID ,
                    acs.CategoryID ,
                    SUM(acs.Points) Points
          FROM      acs
          GROUP BY  acs.UserID ,
                    acs.RoleID ,
                    acs.CategoryID
        ) P
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    tb.UserID ,
                                tb.RoleID ,
                                tb.CategoryID ,
                                SUM(( (DATEDIFF(dd, ( CASE WHEN @start >= tb.StartDate THEN @start
                                                           ELSE tb.StartDate
                                                      END ), ( CASE WHEN @end <= tb.EndDate THEN @end
                                                                    ELSE tb.EndDate
                                                               END )) + 1) ) * tb.dailyMed) AS Target
                      FROM      TB
                      WHERE     TB.UserID = P.UserID
                                AND TB.RoleID = P.RoleID
                                AND TB.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
                      GROUP BY  tb.UserID ,
                                tb.RoleID ,
                                tb.CategoryID
                    ) T
```

Comment: Sorry, I have group by clauses in my query. I will give this a go. Thanks

Comment: This works but it is still taking two mins to run through. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you take a look at the execution plan, does it suggest any additional indexes?

Answer (score -2):

could you post the query that your are using for the inner join ? usually, if there are useful indexes on the join columns, the query should perform well.

If not, a good option is to create two temporary tables, 1 to store the result of each query. Then create indexes on the temp tables on the join columns. Run your final query, using the temp tables.

Comment: -1 This is really just guessing. The first part should be a comment.

Comment: @Jacco it's not really guessing, creating or using an index is probably the correct answer here.  I do agree that the first part should be a comment though.  SQLSuperGuru, can you kindly Format your answer a little nicer and move your question to a comment?

Comment: The Database is properly indexed, My initial solution was to utilise temporary tables however this solution was much slower than what I have now.